# not able to import IdentityModel in .net core

Tags: c#, token, visual-studio-code

Currently I am Trying to set up a token for authentication. In able to do this, I wish to use Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, however i get the following error:

[image: Picture displaying the error.]

How can I be missing an assembly reference? Any tips on changing the assembly reference?

Comment: what is the error?. Did you add the using to the top of your class?

Comment: "Hi garage, my car does not work, can you tell me what the problem is?" - come on dude give us a little help :D

Comment: Sorry about the lack of information. Not sure how to state the problem, however I am simply not able to import the IdentityModel. Does this help?